# This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK using (Angular 12 SSR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-rendering, angular12

I am getting firebase (messaging/unsupported-browser) error when I am trying to run my project with server side rendering. Without server side rendering firebase messaging working fine but when I am trying to run using server side rendering I am getting browser unsupported error. Server side rendering also working fine when I am not using firebase messaging library in my project. I am trying to resolve to this issue for last three days but cannot find any proper solution.

**Note:** Issue only with SSR otherwise messaging working fine

**Error**

[image]

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

[image]

**server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
import { createWindow } from 'domino';
const scripts = readFileSync('dist/index.html').toString();
const window = createWindow(scripts) as any;
(global as any).window = window;
(global as any).self = window;
(global as any).document = window.document;
(global as any).Event = window.Event;
(global as any).KeyboardEvent = window.KeyboardEvent;
(global as any).MouseEvent = window.MouseEvent;
(global as any).navigator = window.navigator;
// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: How do you load `firebase-messaging-sw.js`? Probably through a `<script src="/firebase-messaging-sw.js">` I guess? In what file?

Comment: I have solved it using `@angular/platform-browser` Api.